# How can I install the latest version of Python and pip in Arch Linux?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip, archlinux

My default operating system is [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux), and the Python version installed on it is 3.1.

I installed version 3.9 using [AUR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux#Arch_User_Repository_(AUR)), but I do not know how to systematize this version of Python by default and install pip for it, because when I try to use *pip*, I get this message:

```bash
python3.9 -m pip
```

Output:

```bash
/usr/bin/python3.9: No module named pip
```

Comment: Check this please : https://linuxhint.com/install_pip_archlinux/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pip should be installed normally, and if not, there should be a package for *pip*, but if you cannot install it for whatever reason, installing *pip* can be done via the *ensurepip* module:

```
python -m ensurepip
```

Reference [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ensurepip.html) for more information.